# Как обнулить параметр CURLOPT_URL?

Tags: curl, php

Доброго времени суток.
cURL'ом скачиваю файл,

```
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $url);
$html = curl_exec($this->curl);
```

потом через ту же переменную пытаюсь получить web страницу

```
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FILE, null);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$html = curl_exec($this->curl);
```

PHP(5.3) ругается -

> Warning:  curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in /var/www/wild-parser/parser_v2/lib/web.php on line 137

на php 5.5 проблем нет...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не меняйте опцию `CURLOPT_FILE` – там ожидается валидный файл, `null` не пройдёт.

Вместо этого задайте опцию `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE`, чтобы результат возвращался функцей `curl_exec()`. Это же отменит действие ранее установленой опции `CURL_FILE` в PHP до 5.3.9. После этой версии одного `RETURNTRANSFER` не достаточно. Необходимо ещё вначале выполнить

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
```

И не забудьте отключить HTTP заголовки в ответе: `CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE`.